# Is -[NSCalendar components:fromDate:] available in MonoTouch?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to convert the following Objective-c code to MonoTouch/C#, but I cannot find the `NSCalendar.componentsFromDate()` method. Looks like it is not implemented in MonoTouch. This is the code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
                    [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) 
                                 fromDate:today];
```

that I got from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html); it takes Daylight Saving Time into account.
Any suggestions on how to convert to above code to C#?

Comment: The name of the method is `components:fromDate:`.

Comment: I think you would just use the standard DateTime methods to do this.

Comment: @Josh: yes but does it exist in monotouch? I cannot find it

Comment: @Jason: I can convert an NSDate to DateTime, but it will not be accurate because DateTime does not take into account the daylight saving time. An NSDate is always in UTC and the conversion to DateTime could be e.g. GMT+3 if it is a summer date and GMT+2 if it is a date after October  and this also depends on user locale etc... Thats why apple suggests the above method in their docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on what you're going to do with the result, but if you want the day and weekday of the current date in the current user's locale, this is one way to do it:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var day = now.Day;
var weekday = now.DayOfWeek;
```

*Updated:*

If you have an NSDate, you can do this:

```
var dt = ((DateTime) theNSDate).ToLocalTime ();
var day = now.Day;
var weekday = now.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: I am using EventKit API to retrieve events and simply by converting to DateTime does not work because it is not accurate. For example in GMT+3 time zone the folloing 2 events:

Comment: I am using EventKit API to retrieve events and simply by converting to DateTime does not work because it is not accurate. For example in GMT+3 time zone consider the following two events:
a. 2012-08-01 18:00 and
b. 2012-11-01 18:00.

When retrieving these events using eventkit api they appear like the following NSDate objects:
a. 2012-08-01 15:00 +0000
b. 2012-11-01 16:00 +0000   <<<16:00! because daylight saving time is taken into consideration.
This is why apple suggests to convert an NSDate using an NSCaledar object in their docs.

Comment: This should still work: var now = ((DateTime) (theNSDate)).ToLocalTime ();  since NSDates are considered UTC when converting them to DateTime.

Comment: Looks like the method ((DateTime)(theNSDate)).ToLocalTime () that you are suggesting works fine. I am currently testing it under different usage senarios to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.SpecifyKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx) to create a DateTime object using UTC, or use one of the DateTime constructors that accepts DateTimeKind as an argument

Comment: Thank you Jason. This method does nothing to NSDate conversion. 
For example: if myNSDate = "2012-10-08 21:00 +0000", 
calling DateTime.SpecifyKind(myNSDate,DateTimeKind.Local) or DateTime.SpecifyKind(myNSDate,DateTimeKind.UTC) or DateTime.SpecifyKind(myNSDate,DateTimeKind.Unspecified) always returns the same datetime: "2012-10-08 21:00". I am trying to convert the NSDate based on user selected timezone on his device.

Comment: Sorry, see you tried that.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you just want the current time in UTC, use DateTime.UTCNow.

Comment: Please take a look at the comment I posted on Rolf Bjarne Kvinge answer. This problem is that I want to convert a future event date (NSDate), retrieved using EventKit api and for the convertion to be accurate you have to take into account the user calendar preferenses. NSDate does not store timezone related info.

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(d) will tell you the TimeZone offset for a DateTime d, adjusted for DST.  Does that help?

Comment: It could help but it looks that Rolf's suggestion to use ((DateTime) (theNSDate)).ToLocalTime() is working fine and does all the date math itself.